# How to unpublish or disable webform components without code for d7?

Tags: webforms

**How  to unpublish or disable webform components without code for d7?**

I've seen answers to do this programmatically, but I'm looking for a simple "unpublish" or "disable" field from back end GUI, is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webform itself offers no UI-based method for disabling/un-publishing components.

Unless you can find something in contrib that can help (or perhaps convince the developer of webform to add it as a feature), you'll need custom code to achieve it.

As an example you may be able to configure [Webform Conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_conditional) to disable fields unconditionally, or based on a contrived condition, to simulate the effect. But it wasn't necessarily built for the purpose you need.

Comment: Unbelievable that a 2017 CMS can't do this...!

Comment: It's a module, not the CMS as such. Remember it's only a couple of lines of code to do this for a specific use-case, but considerably more work to make a generic UI-based solution. If I was the Webform module maintainer and I had 272 issues open, 127 of them bug reports, I reckon I wouldn't bother building this feature either. If it's anything more than a niche requirement, you tend to find a contrib solution. I guess in this case it's a relatively niche requirement

Comment: I wouldn't call it niche requirement, all content should have a publish, unpublish and delete option, that's just commons sense, isn't it?

Comment: Content? Absolutely, and it does - all webforms are nodes, and can be published/un-published as you'd expect. The components in a Webform, like the fields in core, are _configuration_, not content. Being able to enable/disable them arbitrarily, rather than just add or remove, makes less sense unless you have a niche requirement (in my opinion)